# How to know what's the error at creating a MULTICAST address in ActiveMQ Artemis from STOMP?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, stomp, activemq-artemis

I'm using STOMP from Angular to connect by Spring Boot in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1. For any reason some MULTICAST addresses are been creating normally like **jms.topic.Inss-1** and **jms.topic.Inss-111**, but the **jms.topic.Inss-114** is not.

- *I already validate my disk usage and it's ok.*
- *I already disable my firewall and it's not working.*

In the log file INFO level:

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:47146: AMQ339016 Error creating subscription sub-1
```

ALL level:

```
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl] registered address org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="jms.topic.Inss-114"
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl]registered queue org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="jms.topic.Inss-114",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="multicast",queue="e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61"
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl] Queue e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61 created on address jms.topic.Inss-114 with filter=null temporary = true durable=false on session user=admin, connection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection@70674c9
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] QueueImpl[name=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl[server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=022fac19-ef63-11e9-a5eb-f23c91899d61], temp=true]@402f950f adding consumer ServerConsumerImpl [id=45306157,filter=null, binding=LocalQueueBinding address=jms.topic.Inss-114, queue=QueueImpl[name=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl[server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=022fac19-ef63-11e9-a5eb-f23c91899d61], temp=true]@402f950f, filter=null, name=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, clusterName=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61022fac19-ef63-11e9-a5eb-f23c91899d61]]
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl] Session with user=admin, connection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection@70674c9 created a consumer on queue e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, filter = null 
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl] ServerConsumerImpl [id=45306157, filter=null, binding=LocalQueueBinding [address=jms.topic.Inss-114, queue=QueueImpl[name=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=022fac19-ef63-11e9-a5eb-f23c91899d61], temp=true]@402f950f, filter=null, name=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, clusterName=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61022fac19-ef63-11e9-a5eb-f23c91899d61]]::FlowControl::Received disable flow control message
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] QueueImpl[name=e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=022fac19-ef63-11e9-a5eb-f23c91899d61], temp=true]@402f950f doing deliver. messageReferences=0 
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl] deleting temporary queue e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61 
DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] no queue to delete "e45ece7f-fa8a-11e9-bacb-f23c91899d61." 
WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:41504: AMQ339016 Error creating subscription sub-1
```

I expect the clear error message to understand my problem.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem is the topic/queue name. When I apply a crypto algorithm to my topic/queue name, is working. Now my topic/queues has names like this **jms.topic.Inss_XXXXXXX**

Comment: Why are you using the `jms.topic.` prefix? That hasn't been necessary since 2.0 was released over 2 years ago now.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense that changing your naming convention to use `_` instead of `-` solved the problem. You said yourself that sometimes names with `-` were working and `-` characters are often used internally for address/queue names. There's likely something else going on.